# Create-React-App on Github-pages returns a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, create-react-app

When testing locally my create-react-quiz app works perfectly. I was basing my project off of this code: https://github.com/mitchgavan/react-multi-choice-quiz/tree/gh-pages.

However, when I use npm build deploy on my "GitHub-Pages" branch, a blank page shows up and these errors show up in the console: 
**pk8189.github.io/:1 GET pk8189.github.io/pk8189/futureU-/static/css/main.1dc4d41f.css 
pk8189.github.io/:1 GET pk8189.github.io/pk8189/futureU-/static/js/main.28e294a0.js**

This is my repo: https://github.com/pk8189/futureU- 
What do you think the issue is? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 11):

Create React App uses `homepage` field in your `package.json` to determine the URL at which the app is served. Since you [set it to `https://github.com/pk8189/futureU-/`](https://github.com/pk8189/futureU-/blob/823fca132dd06d9661f46c2488770bbb982476a8/package.json#L5), it tries to request assets from `/pk8189/futureU-/` which doesn't exist.

Change `homepage` to match your deployed URL: `https://pk8189.github.io/futureU-/`. Then rebuild by running `npm run build` and re-deploy.

This is described in [deployment instructions for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages). Please read this part of the User Guide.

Comment: Thank you so much! Trying now.

Comment: Link outdated, new link: is https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Comment: @Dan Abramov: Why BrowserRouter not working with gh-pages? I was trying to deploy react-create-app to gh-pages with BrowserRouter but seeing only a blank page. Now I just replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter and it's working pretty fine.